# How to use CTAS from a table having LONG column? Cant even use alter table ... move tablespace here

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table

```
acct_log  (
date_created date,
log_desc  long
log_key number  primary key)
```

In oracle 12c.

This table has grown to 45 GB.
I purge this using date_created -- for rows older than 7 days, daily.

This script has failed for the past 21 days, now too many rows accumulated in this.

I tried to use `alter table acct_log  move` command - but it fails on `LONG` column. This works on any table with all other types of columns BUT NOT LONG.

Can anyone help me -- I cant even use CTAS to create a temporary table as it fails with

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype
```

Comment: LONG **should not** be used anymore. Use LOBs

Comment: @GurV year, a 20 years old statement - and still valid!

Comment: you've obviously had this table for a long while, but your purge script has only been failing for 21 days?  What is the error you get for your purge script?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a special tool just for this issue: [`to_lob`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions221.htm#SQLRF06134):

> TO_LOB converts LONG or LONG RAW values in the column long_column to LOB values. You can apply this function only to a LONG or LONG RAW column, and only in the select list of a subquery in an INSERT statement.

**Example**

```
create table foo (a number, b date, c long);

insert into foo values(1, sysdate - 1, 'Parfümök százai, virágok álmai');
insert into foo values(2, sysdate - 2, 'Édeskés, kesernyés, mézédes felejtés');
insert into foo values(3, sysdate - 3, 'Rózsa és leander, karcsú kis üveggel, oh elkábít');
insert into foo values(4, sysdate - 4, 'Mirha és mandula kis helyre bezárva, orgonák, violák titkos kis fiolák');
insert into foo values(5, sysdate - 5, 'Cseppenként, permetként próbálom egyenként úgy elbódít');

commit;

create table bar as select a, b, to_lob(c) as c from foo;
```

**Results**

```
SQL> desc bar

Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
A                                                  NUMBER
B                                                  DATE
C                                                  CLOB
```